# Posting from a site to Ektron

Tags: ektron

I have a free standing .net site(3.5) and an Ektron installation running on another server. I want to post a form from my .net site to Ektron.

How would I do this using the web services API? (/Workarea/webservices/WebServiceAPI/Content/Form.asmx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a SOAP request to the webservice with the details of the form fields. If you go to the webservice in your browser `www.yoursite.com/Workarea/webservices/WebServiceAPI/Content/Form.asmx` it will have a list of operations for the webservice, as well as example SOAP requests and responses.